# Libgdx font height

Tags: java, fonts, libgdx

Does anyone know what is the formula to calculate height of bitmap font with specific size? I know that when I draw a string on a screen I'm creating a rectangle to do that and I want to know what is the height of this rectangle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using LibGDX version >= 1.5.6 then you can get height of font by [GlyphLayout](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/GlyphLayout.java).

```
Bitmap font = new BitmapFont();
GlyphLayout layout = new GlyphLayout(); 
layout.setText(font, "meow");
float height = layout.height;  //height of "meow"
```

but if still you're using LibGDX API < 1.5.6, you can get height by this

```
float height = font.getBounds("meow").height;
```

Comment: Thanks, it's very useful :)